# Spring @Value annotation usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Please see the code below. Even though I set the `spring.profiles.active=qa` it still overrides the last value which is `dev-YAML`. Any idea why? I do not want to use `@ConfigurationProperties` etc. I would like to use `@Value` annotation.

```java
 @Value("${name}")
 private String name;

//application.yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
name: prod-YAML
---
spring:
  profiles:
    active: qa
name: qa-YAML
---
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
name: dev-YAML
```

Comment: either pass `spring.profiles.active=qa-YAML` or assign qa to name like so : `name: qa`

Comment: Where did you see that a profile is specified with `active: prod`??? It should be `profiles: prod` and remove all your `active:` keys. You're not specifying the profile anywhere in your yaml file so it uses the latest.

Comment: As I mentioned above Even though I set the spring.profiles.active=qa . I do this in my IDEs run settings-program arguments. and I checked it sets properly via @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;

Comment: You don't specify the profiles in your yaml file

Comment: Yes, not in the yaml but I pass it as program argument just like in my IDE run configurations basically same thing with -Dspring.profiles.active=qa from command line.

Comment: Yes, I will try to explain myself better. You're specifying the `qa` profile correctly which spring will use. However you don't actually specify properties that will be used by this profile. Your `application.yaml` file is wrong. You should remove the `active: qa` line and all the other `active` lines and change `profiles:` line which is above it to `profiles: qa` the same with all the other `profile: ` lines.

Comment: ahh! I see your point now. You are right. I missed that point. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use @Configuration or @ConfigurationProperties, you have to move your configuration to other stereotypes such as @Service, @Controller, @RestController... classes

```
@Value("${name}")
private String name;
```

Don't forget to activate your profile via arg `-Dspring.profiles.active=active-profile`